# Using SQL Server bcp to migrate data from datetime to datetimeoffset

Tags: sql-server, datetime, bcp

I have two tables with almost the same structure, one in *SQL Server 2005* and the other in *SQL Server 2016*. The only difference is that column `ModifiedDate` is of type `datetime` in *SQL 2005* and `datetimeoffset` in *SQL 2016*.

I used bcp to export the data from *SQL 2005* in native format to a file. Then I tried to use bcp to import the data file to *SQL 2016*. I got error:

> [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server] Invalid field size for datatype

If I removed `ModifiedDate` column, export/import would run without any errors.

Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you export with BCP, instead of doing an `OUT` export directly for a table, do a `QUERYOUT` export with a query that converts the `DATETIME` field to a field with a format that is convertible to `DATETIMEOFFSET`.

Comment: That's not an option. The two databases are different domains and I have to use files.

Comment: @user3616544 You're still using "files" in what I described. The `QUERYOUT` export is still an export to a file. I don't really understand what you are referring to.